# How to assign models to $scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

According to best practices I read about, in my controller, I assign a model to the $scope  rather than assignging multiple separate values to $scope:

```
  .controller('TestCtrl', function AboutCtrl($scope, $http) {

    var model = {
        name: 'Bob',
        address: 'Squaresville'
        }
    };

    $scope = model;
})
```

And in my template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.name" /> {{model.name}}
<input type="text" ng-model="model.address" /> {{model.address}}
```

But when the page initially loads, the text boxes have no value.  But as I type, the matching `{{...}}` tags get updated.

Why doesn't the initial value get updated?

Comment: remove `model.` in your markup

Comment: you are setting your $scope to model ($scope=model). You should be doing $scope.model = model;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$scope.model = model;
```

Or just define it that way:

```
$scope.model = {
    name: "Bob",
    address: "squaresville"
}
```

Comment: Woo!, thanks. But do you know why my way did what it did (allow updates but not initial values?)

Comment: You crushed the $scope variable, shouldn't be doing that :)

Comment: @Cabbagesocks Just remember when referring to this value in your markup to include `model` so... `<input ng-model="model.name">` and not `<input ng-model="name">`

Answer (score 2):

There is a shorter way to do what you want:

```
$scope.model = {
        name: 'Bob',
        address: 'Squaresville'
        };
```